# Google Charts in Thymeleaf Spring . Javascript Loop

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I need help with the code. I want to create google charts based on array list. I don't know java script, and I have a loop problem. I posted the code in which I want to return data. Instead of single printing, I want to insert a loop. So that you don't have to enter e.g. / * [[$ {FirstAirline}]] * / ....

I will return data.price and data.destination from the list

Front :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/connect/historical}" th:object="${FlightDTO}" method="post">

    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Airline', 'Price [[${Currency}]] '],
          [ /*[[${FirstAirline}]]*/, [[${FirstFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${SecondAirline}]]*/,[[${SecondFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${ThirdAirline}]]*/, [[${ThirdFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${FourthAirline}]]*/, [[${FourthFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${FifthAirline}]]*/, [[${FifthFlight}]]],

          [ /*[[${SixthAirline}]]*/, [[${SixthFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${SeventhAirline}]]*/, [[${SeventhFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${EighthAirline}]]*/, [[${EighthFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${NinthAirline}]]*/, [[${NinthFlight}]]],
          [ /*[[${TenthAirline}]]*/, [[${TenthFlight}]]],


         [ "Average month price", /*[[${Average}]]*/]

        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 800,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: {
            title: 'The cheapest cheapfly prices at  [[${Date}]] ',
            subtitle: 'from [[${Departure}]] to [[${Destination}]]' },
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'top', label: 'White to move'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      };
       /*]]>*/
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="top_x_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

BackEnd :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/chart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @AllowedForUsers
    public String chart(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightRequest,
                        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


        ArrayList<Historical> historicalList = historicalFlightRepository.findByUserName(CurrentUserName().getUsername());

        for (Historical his : historicalList) {
            if (his.getId() == null) {

                throw new HistoricalNotFoundException();

            }
        }
        // model.addAttribute("currency",historicalList.)
        model.addAttribute("average", service.averagePrice(historicalList));
        model.addAttribute("data", historicalList);


        return "historical/chart.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this wrong.  Instead of trying to loop through the data in Thymeleaf, you should instead be structuring your data for JavaScript libraries before you add it to the model.  For example, with this model attribute:

```
model.addAttribute("data", new Object[][] {
    {"Airline",     "Price $"},
    {"Delta",       100},
    {"Southwest",   500},
    {"Jet Blue",    300},
    {"Canada Air",  300},
    {"Average month price", 300}
});
```

Then, in the JavaScript, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    var data = [[${data}]];
</script>
```

will output this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [["Airline","Price $"],["Delta",100],["Southwest",500],["Jet Blue",300],["Canada Air",300],["Average month price",300]];
</script>
```

Comment: thank You! But is it only way to do this ? It doesn't looks clean ..  Are You sure ? Can't I make loop in front from data list ?

Comment: You can do loops like this: [Thymeleaf textual syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#natural-javascript-and-css-templates#textual-template-modes).  (But you really don't want to have to do that.)  Thymeleaf can already convert your Java objects to JavaScript arrays, you just need to find the format that feels right to you I guess.